# Enumerate database tables with JDBI

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dropwizard, jdbi

Is there a way, using JDBI, to get information about what tables are contained in the schema?

I have two databases *A* and *B*, and I need to be able to

1. query *A* and retrieve a list of tables from it;
2. query *B* and check that those same tables exist and have the same definitions (I don't care about the data in the tables).

I can do this using `mysqldump` from the command line: retrieve the `CREATE TABLE` statements from each database and compare them. But now I need to do it as part of a test, in a Dropwizard/JDBI context.

The documentation is a bit sparse, but I can't find anything suitable to enable me to do it. I might be able to

```
handle.execute("show tables");
```

etc., but that seems a bit low level, and I was hoping there would be a better way.

Or do I need to resort to JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

JDBC has several database provider independent mechanisms.

From the connection you can get [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html), and do a query-by-expression on it (null = any).

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = meta.getColumns(...);
```

Beware: names may be case-sensitive here and such.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself.  *JDBI* doesn't provide a high-level API to do what you're asking so you'll need to use the *JDBC* APIs.  That said, just in case you aren't aware, JDBI provides access to the underlying `Connection` object as an entry point to JDBC:

```java
DBI dbi = ...;
try (Handle h = dbi.open()) {
  try (Connection c = h.getConnection()) {
    try (ResultSet tables = c.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, "%", "%")) {
      // loop over columns/tables here...
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on your requirements you could also take a look at [Liquibase's diff](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) feature which does what you're looking for out of the box:

```
liquibase.sh --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
        --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@testdb:1521:test \
        --username=bob \
        --password=bob \
    diff \
        --referenceUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE \
        --referenceUsername=bob \
        --referencePassword=bob
```